# Global or local id for views inside a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

When assigning an id to a view of a layout in an xml resource, I usually do something like  this:

(example)
contact_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_info_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here the TextView contains the name of a contact.
Is it better to use a complete id like that or just "name" is enough?

Comment: That depends entirely on how many elements there are and whether or not you're going to reference it.

Comment: Its always better to name any view so that it is self explanatory.
For this u could have used txt_contact_info_name, which will tell me its a text view. By using prefix like these you will know about the view's type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appropriate convention would be like this: 
From the example you have provided, the appropriate id for the text view would be: `contactinfo_textview_name`

Please note that, its NOT rule. You can use anything you are comfortable with! cheers

Answer (score 0):

As I indicated Hardik4560, it is best to names that are sufficiently descriptive and not too long.

Realize that your application can grow much (who knows!?) and there may come a time when no longer know to which each identifier belongs layout.

Regards!